# With an LSTM, with training samples on 0->250, should it be able to extrapolate to unseen data(e.g. 250->500)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm, tensorflow

I'm currently training on a simple dataset:
Training: [0,1,2,3,4,5...250]
Test: [251-500]

My training cost and expected output decreases and seems correct. However, when I test the model, my network doesn't seem to be able to predict sequences higher than 250. Is there an issue with my model, perhaps not deep enough?

```
class Model:

    def __init__(self, n_steps, n_hidden, batch_size, feature_len=1):
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, n_steps, feature_len])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 1])

        self.lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden)
        state = self.lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

        self.w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, 1]))
        self.b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))

        outputs = []
        with tf.variable_scope("lstm") as scope:
            for i in range(n_steps):
                if i > 0:
                    scope.reuse_variables()
                output, state = self.lstm(self.x[:, i, :], state)
                outputs.append(output)

        self.outputs = outputs
        self.final_state = state

        self.final_output = self.outputs[-1]

        self.result = tf.matmul(self.final_output, self.w) + self.b
        self.cost = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.y[0] - self.result[0])))

        opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
        gvs = opt.compute_gradients(self.cost)
        capped_gvs = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -1., 1.), var) for grad, var in gvs]
        self.optimizer = opt.apply_gradients(capped_gvs)

n_epochs = 2000
n_steps = 5
batch_size = 1
feature_len = 1
data = load_data('add1.txt', seq_len=n_steps, batch_size=batch_size, feature_len=feature_len, normalise_window=False)
print(data['x_train'][0])

m = Model(n_steps=n_steps-1, n_hidden=50, batch_size=batch_size)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    x,y = sess.run([m.y,m.result], feed_dict={m.x:data['x_train'][0], m.y:  data['y_train'][0]})
    print(x,y,x-y)
    for step in range(n_epochs):
        for batch_idx in range(data['x_train'].shape[0]):
            out = sess.run(m.optimizer, feed_dict={m.x:data['x_train'][batch_idx], m.y:  data['y_train'][batch_idx]})
            # out = sess.run(outputs)
            # tf.Print(outputs, [outputs], message="TESTING!!")
            if step % 100 == 0:
                cost,y,x = sess.run([m.cost,m.result, m.x], feed_dict={m.x:data['x_train'][batch_idx], m.y:  data['y_train'][batch_idx]})
                print("Cost\n",cost,'\nPredicted\n',y,'\nInput\n',x)

                # cost, expected,actual = sess.run([m.cost, m.y, m.result], feed_dict={m.x:data['x_train'][batch_idx], m.y:  data['y_train'][batch_idx]})
                # print("Expected\n",expected,'\nActual\n',actual, '\nCost\n',cost)
    for i in range(data['x_test'].shape[0]):
        cost, expected,actual = sess.run([m.cost, m.y, m.result], feed_dict={m.x:data['x_test'][i], m.y:  data['y_test'][i]})
        print("Expected\n",expected,'\nActual\n',actual, '\nCost\n',cost, data['x_test'][i])
```

Answer (score 1):

LSTMs are not very good at extrapolating to unseen regions in data. The main problem is that a traditional LSTM relies a lot on sigmoidal functions (gates are typically logistic sigmoids and the activation function is $\tanh$ by default).
These functions tend to saturate when values become too small or too large.
As a result, the parameters will be optimised in such a way that large activations map to saturation on one side and small values map to saturation on the other side.
If the numerical values happen to be outside of the range of values seen during training, this will typically result in more (unforeseen) saturation of these sigmoid functions and therefore poor performance.

If you can get rid of the sigmoidal functions somehow, you might be able to get reasonable predictions for values outside of the training range.
It seems like the MC-LSTM architecture from [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v139/hoedt21a.html) aims to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

your training data is way too small for testing , as a rule of thumb you should have at least 10 times the test data.  that is what learning theory says , for a more rigorous proof check any article on "vc dimension" and learning theory . however for an lstm to work you should have much much more training data